# Locking mouse movement on one particular screen using C#

Tags: c#, screen, mouse

I have 2 screens connected to my computer. I also have a HotKey control that can trigger a function call in my application even when it is not focused.

I need to do the following. When I start my C# application, my mouse should be locked only to the current screen (meaning that it shouldn't be able to go on to the other screen). On pressing the HotKey, it should be get locked onto the second screen and not be able to move on the first screen. So basically the HotKey (essentially a function call) should allow toggling between the two screens and restricting mouse movement only to that screen.

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF ?

Comment: Windows is not a mouse trap.  The user can always get out with a simple Ctrl+Escape.

Comment: I am using creating a process (opening a browser) in my console application and placing the application on another screen. I need the hotkey to enable or disable focus to that process which is open on another screen. No use of WPF/WinForms.

Comment: @PiyushW I updated my answer with the link to WinAPI function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Cursor.Clip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.clip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. E.g.`Cursor.Clip = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea`

Without WinForms you can use [ClipCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling=true)]
public static extern bool ClipCursor(ref RECT rcClip);
```

Comment: This looks helpful but how do I get the RECT structure working in C#? I am relatively new at C#.

Comment: I got some lead on this page: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.clipcursor

Now I am wondering how to unconfine my cursor, ie. set it back to its default behavior.

Comment: For reverting back to original setting I am using a workaround where I provide huge values to the RECT structure which are obviously outside the bounds. Can anyone comment on what is the correct way to do it?

Comment: "If this parameter is NULL, the cursor is free to move anywhere on the screen."